# Css styling error with the widget aligning a div in the centre of a td

Tags: javascript, css, widget, html-table

See the sample widget at http://jsfiddle.net/4B2Bc/
The problem is that the image and the text below the image should be centered in the td, whereas it is aligned left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
.w_61532_article
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

to

```
.w_61532_article
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And you are fully centered.

Comment: sorry, I wanna have left alignment for the text but I wanna align the .w_61532_article in center of the td. Thanks for a quick reply. I have been trying for the whole day but couldn't work out whats wrong.

Comment: You know what mate...Seriously. 1 up vote and accepted answer for you...Btw, I would appreciate if you explain to me what margin 0 auto does that text align doesn't...

Comment: The `auto` just tells the browser to split up the available space evenly between the left and right side of the element. By available space, I mean any unoccupied horizontal space between the left and right edges of the parent container.

Comment: Because the DIV was the full width of the TD element. If you were to delete the width of the article class; it would have looked closer to what you expected. ALthough, your text would still be off center.